# Data frame not changing with rbind

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

This seems like it should be quite simple.  I thought I would make a little timesheet function so I can track my time at work.  Below is the code:

```
timesheet <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 3))
varn <- c("date", "project", "status")
colnames(timesheet) <- varn

timesheet[1,] <- c(date(), "test", "test") 
#The above line exists because rbind was renaming the columns otherwise

new.task <- function(project){
  timesheet <- append(time, c(date(), project, "started"))
}

new.task("Name of task")
```

However the dataframe remains unchanged without throwing an error.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

The reason lies in the concept of lexical scoping and "environments" in R as memory spaces:

"timesheet" object is declared at the Global Environment. However the "timesheet" object that your code tries to append is declared within the scope of the "new.task" function. So the "append" command just appends to the local "timesheet", not the global one.

To illustrate the scoping and environments, I added some informatory lines to your code:

```
library(pryr)

timesheet <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 3)) 
varn <- c("date", "project", "status")
colnames(timesheet) <- varn

timesheet[1,] <- c(date(), "test", "test") 
#The above line exists because rbind was renaming the columns otherwise

print(environment())
print(ls(environment()))
sprintf("address of timesheet object is %s", pryr::address(timesheet))

new.task <- function(project){
    timesheet <- append(time, c(date(), project, "started"))
    print(environment())
    print(ls(environment()))
    sprintf("address of timesheet object is %s", pryr::address(timesheet))
}

new.task("Name of task")
```

"pryr" library is loaded to get the memory address of objects.
When we source the code, first:

- the name/address of the global environment
- the list of objects in the global environment
- and the memory address of the "timesheet" object in the global environment

are printed.

Since the last line runs the "new.task" function, later the three infos are printed within the new.task function. See the differences:

```
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
[1] "new.task"  "timesheet" "varn"     
[1] "address of timesheet object is 0x365b8e8"
<environment: 0x32ef750>
[1] "project"   "timesheet"
[1] "address of timesheet object is 0x365dbb8"
```

In order to correct this issue, you should superassign (a way to modify an object that exists in the global environment from another scope) with the "<<-" operator as follows:

```
new.task <- function(project){
  timesheet <<- append(time, c(date(), project, "started"))
}
```

But there are two more errors in your code:

- You try to append to "time" not timesheet, and "time" by itself is a closure, a built-in function.
- Append works for vectors or lists. But when you try to append to a dataframe, it is converted into a list.

So the correct form should be like this (you can use rbind as well):

```
timesheet[nrow(timesheet)+1,] <<- c(date(), project, "started")
```

And another way to modify a global object without superassignment operator is to refer to it with its environment as follows:

```
timesheet <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 3))
varn <- c("date", "project", "status")
colnames(timesheet) <- varn

timesheet[1,] <- c(date(), "test", "test")
#The above line exists because rbind was renaming the columns otherwise

envg <- environment()

new.task <- function(project, env = envg){
    env$timesheet[nrow(env$timesheet)+1,] <- c(date(), project, "started")
}

new.task("Name of task")
```

Comment: Wow, yes there were a few issues with my question.  I switched out rbind for append and changed all but one variable name but I'm glad you saw the root of the problem.  Thank you very much!